# JGraphT - Finding path with BreadthFirstIterator

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

Here is the code to traverse the graph with `BreathFirstIterator`:

```
public class GraphTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirectedGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> graph = 
            new DefaultDirectedGraph <Integer, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

        graph.addVertex(7);
        graph.addVertex(4);
        graph.addVertex(9);
        graph.addVertex(3);
        graph.addVertex(2);
        graph.addVertex(5);


        graph.addEdge(7, 4);
        graph.addEdge(7, 9);
        graph.addEdge(9, 3);
        graph.addEdge(3, 2);
        graph.addEdge(3, 5);

        GraphIterator<Integer, DefaultEdge> iterator = 
                new BreadthFirstIterator<Integer, DefaultEdge>(graph);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println( iterator.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the code prints out the list of all visited vertexes: `7,4,9,3,2,5`. My problem is - I don't know how can I use this API to obtain a path with removed backtracks of algorithm. For example, for path from 7 to 2, it would output `7->9->3->2`, and not just the list of visited vertexes. Stopping it after reaching the destination is obsiously not enough. Have anyone already solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the shortest path between two vertices with [`DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html#findPathBetween-org.jgrapht.Graph-V-V-). It provides an implementation of [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) using `ClosestFirstIterator`. If there is no such path, it will return `null`.

Sample code:

```
DirectedGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> graph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);

graph.addVertex(7);
graph.addVertex(4);
graph.addVertex(9);
graph.addVertex(3);
graph.addVertex(2);
graph.addVertex(5);

graph.addEdge(7, 4);
graph.addEdge(7, 9);
graph.addEdge(9, 3);
graph.addEdge(3, 2);
graph.addEdge(3, 5);

List<DefaultEdge> path = DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(graph, 7, 2);
System.out.println(path); // prints [(7 : 9), (9 : 3), (3 : 2)]
```

Comment: I already have a solution for finding shortest path with Dijkstra algorithm, but in this case I don't want the shortest path - I want ANY path that can be found with BFS (probably with the fewest "jumps").

Comment: @Niemand Well the path with the fewest jumps is the shortest path as found by Dijkstra algorithm. So do you want all of them or just the shortest one?

Comment: In this simplified case in question yes, the Dijkstra can be used. But in my real example i have a weighted edge and I want to find the path specifically with breadth first search and ignore the weights, minimazing the number of transfers between nodes. So to conclude - I want to have an algorithm that finds one single path with the fewest number of transfers regardless of the edge weight. BFS seemed like a good choice to me.

Comment: @Niemand This is a _completely_ different question that the one you asked. It doesn't involve `DirectedGraph` at all but `WeightedGraph` which is quite different. You do not mention weights at all in your question.

Comment: Maybe I simplified my case too much :) I will try to fix it in a moment

Comment: @Niemand Please don't edit your post as you will change enormously the question that you asked. I suggest you create another question that is more specific to your use-case. This one might be helpful for future visitors wanting to have an example of Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: OK, I will leave it as-is. The new question moved here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935692/jgrapht-apply-bfs-to-weightedgraph