# Getting the shortest number of paths irrelevant of the weight JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht, jgraph

I'm trying to find/create an algorithm to find the least number of edges to traverse to, to get to a vertex.

I am using a `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph`, but I don't want to use Dijkstra's algorithm because I want to omit the weights doing this.

Is there a built in method/class that can help me do this, or an algorithm I can use?

Comment: If the weights are ignored, the shortest path (in terms of number of edges) can be found using BFS. See this answer [JGraphT - apply BFS to WeightedGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935692/jgrapht-apply-bfs-to-weightedgraph)